# PHP/SOAP dont create desired xml request

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I am trying to use a WSDL web service with php/soap. And it always gives a deserializing error which is exactly:

> Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'Test'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'Test' and namespace ''. Found node type 'Element' with name 'parameters' and 'namespace'

When I test the WSDL source with WcfTestClient software nothing goes wrong and it returns with  desired results.

When I compare the request XML which created by SOAP and XML which created by WcfTestClient software, I see that difference may be the problem. It seem like something wrong with namespace and prefixes, but I don't know how to solve it, or maybe it is something else causes the problem.

The request XMLs is this: http://pastebin.com/eysnG89F.

In case you need PHP code, [this is the code I am using](http://pastebin.com/mGbh8iU3).

```
try{
        $soap_options = array(
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
            'cache_wsdl'   => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'trace' => TRUE
        );
        $soap = new SoapClient(
            'http://url.to/web/service.svc?wsdl', $soap_options
        );
        $a = $soap->Test(
           array("login" => 
               array(
                   "FirmaId"      => 15, 
                   "KullaniciAdi" => "Asdf", 
                   "Parola"       => "Xyxy",
               )
           )
         );
        var_dump($a);
} catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: You PHP code is missing. Also the WSDL URI is missing. Every of the elements have a *different* name which leads to the assumption that something is done fundamentally wrong. Like not using the WSDL with your SOAP client?

Comment: Edited to add PHP code. I cant give the exact url to service, sorry for that. I used Soap 1 because soap 2 gives content type error which is 'Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="urn:VWService/Test"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

Comment: This XML is still missing: `http://url.to/web/service.svc?wsdl` (the WSDL document)

Comment: As i said i cant share the exact link to the WSDL. Im sorry for that. It works well with other tools like soapUI or WcfTestClient. Do you think WSDL document causes error. By the way thanks for your interest.

Comment: Well I can not say, however, if you don't share the WSDL there is not much what anyone could do about that. Because it is a central component in your mix here. It's like asking "why does my car not start?" and then showing a picture of a car that you love most and saying: but I can't show you my car, but here, this is my favorite car. Can you help me getting my car to run while looking at this picture of my dream-car? Won't work.

Comment: You are right, i thought someone came up with same issue and say something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant find the exact cause and solution but this seems like working.

First, when you give object instead of array for the wsdl method, you can get rid of item, value nodes. Node will be created by object name

```
$a = $soap->Test(
       (object)array("login" => 
           (object)array(
               "FirmaId"      => 15, 
               "KullaniciAdi" => "Asdf", 
               "Parola"       => "Xyxy",
           )
       )
     );
```

After that i realized an < parameters> node instead of < WsdlMethod> node created in request xml. With overriding __doRequest method and replacing strings, can get rid this problem but still cant see the response. Need to wrap < wsdlMethodResponse> node with < parameter> via str_replace and finally get desired response.

As i said this may be a temporary solution. But working for me :)